What does SIZE in glcmTexture function in GEE mean?
I´m using entropy and GLCM function of Google Earth Engine.This is my code
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[118.82488789073328, 31.189561414050857],
          [118.82488789073328, 31.020240097401114],
          [119.09611286631922, 31.020240097401114],
          [119.09611286631922, 31.189561414050857]]]);

function rmCloud(image) {
  var DilatedCloudBitMask = (1 << 1);
  var CirrusBitMask = (1 << 2);
  var CloudsBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var CloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 4);
  var SnowBitMask = (1 << 5);
  
  var qa = image.select("QA_PIXEL");
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(DilatedCloudBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(CirrusBitMask).eq(0))
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(CloudsBitMask).eq(0))
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(CloudShadowBitMask).eq(0))
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(SnowBitMask).eq(0));
  
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2').filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31').filterBounds(roi).map(rmCloud).select('SR_B5').median().clip(roi);

var glcm = L8.toInt().glcmTexture({size: 3}).select(['SR_B5_corr']);

Map.addLayer(glcm)

I want to know what is the meaning of SIZE parameter? Is it a neighborhood range?
And I found that when I use different zoom scales, the corr value changes.


It looks like the values ​​when zooming in are correct.If I want to use the sampleRegions function to make training samples for RF, will this change affect it?

It's the window size in which the GLCM is computed.

See https://prism.ucalgary.ca/items/8833a1fc-5efb-4b9b-93a6-ac4ff268091c

Thank you for the wonderful answer! I have got the hint!
